# Failure Reason No code signature found is coming when I try to run in iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

When I run my project in the simulator it's working fine, but when I try to run it in test iPhone xCode is displaying this error. I tried many things, but nothing seems to work out.

And this issue has happened when I am switching from one branch to another.

I tried :

1. Clear build, removing DerivedData
2. Restart Xcode, Mac
3. Code signing identifier :iOS Developer
4. Removed/added .xcworkspace

[[image]]

[[image]]

Comment: Have you selected you Apple ID account in Xcode->Target->Signing & Capabilities?

Comment: yes, i did. but no use.

Comment: Do you have any framework in your app? Are all of them being signed?

Comment: I am using pod files, it has some frameworks. But this problem is not happening with any other projects of mine.

Comment: do you use Xcode 11.2.1 or below @komara ?